# Is it possible to terminate an already running delayed job using Ruby Threading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Let's say I have delayed_job running in the background. Tasks can be scheduled or run immediately(some are long tasks some are not)

If a task is too long, a user should be able to cancel it. Is it possible in delayed job? I checked the docs and can't seem to find a terminate method or something. They only provide a catch to cancel delayed job itself(thus cancelling all tasks...I need to just cancel a certain running task)

**UPDATE**
My boss(who's a great programmer btw) suggested to use Ruby Threading for this feature of ours. Is this possible? Like creating new threads per task and killing that thread while it's running?

something like:

```
t1 = Thread.new(task.run)
self.delay.t1.join (?) -- still reading on threads so correct me if im wrong
```

then to stop it i'll just use t1.stop (?) again don't know yet

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information about the type of job that you're trying to run concurrently? Perhaps Delayed::Job and threading are both poor choices for what you're trying to do.

Comment: For instance, if you're making a service that manages a whole bunch of big tasks that are all reliant on one another, then perhaps it would be better to model them as shell scripts and use Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/) to manage them.

Comment: If you have a bunch of little jobs such as image processing, and every now and then one of them hangs - then maybe delayed_job with many worker processes would be the way to go; and you would provide the capability to kill the hung process from your UI, like @betamatt suggests.

Comment: Or if you never want a process to run for more than X seconds, you can always set Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 60.seconds (http://rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/2.1.4/frames) and they'll timeout automatically (outside of that IO issue I spoke of before.)

Comment: we're running tests(ala cucumber) using threads and delayed_job. there are times when tests take too long so we set a "timeout" for it

Comment: Test suites are _the reason_ continuous integration management tools like Jenkins exist, I would highly suggest trying Jenkins or Integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that my boss hit the spot so here's what we did(please tell us if there's some possibility this is bad practice so I can bring it up):

1. First, we have a Job model that has def execute! (which runs what it's supposed to do).
2. Next, we have **delayed_job** worker in the background, listening for new jobs. Now when you create a job, you can schedule it to run immediately or run every certain day (we use rufus for this one)
3. When a job is created, it checks if its supposed to run immediately. If it is, it adds itself to the delayed job queue. The execute function creates a Thread, so each job has its own thread.
4. User in the ui can see if a job is running(if there's a started_at and no finished_at). If it IS running, there's a button to cancel it. Canceling it just sets the job's canceled_at to Time.now.
5. While the job is running it also checks itself if it has a canceled_at or if `Time.now` is > `finished_at`. If so, kill the thread.

Voila! We've tested it for one job and it seems to work. Now the only problem is scaling...

If you see any problems with this please do so in the comments or give more suggestions if ever :) I hope this helps some one too!

Comment: it's been a while since your post, but did you find this solution to work all right? i'm dealing with the same problem and I think conceptually, your solution seems fine. Please let me know if you had problems with this!

Comment: @hackstar15 I'm sorry we were done with this project since 2012 haha. But as far as I remember, this is the solution we used (my answer). P.S. I don't think we had a problem with this specific solution

Answer (score 2):

`Delayed::Job` is an `< ActiveRecord::Base` model, so you can query it just like you normally would like `Delayed::Job.all(:conditions => {:last_error => nil})`.

Delayed::Job objects have a payload field which contain a serialized version of the method or job that you're attempting to run. This object is accessed by their '#payload_object' method, which loads the object in question.

You can combine these two capabilities to make queriable job workers, for instance, if you have a `User` model, and the user has a paperclip'ed `:avatar`, then you can make a method to delete unprocessed jobs like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :avatar, PaperclipOptions.new(:avatar)
   before_create :'process_avatar_later'

   def process_avatar_later
      filename = Rails.root.join('tmp/avatars_for_processing/',self.id)
      open(filename, 'w') do |file| file <<self.avatar.to_file end
      Delayed::Job.enqueue(WorkAvatar.new(self.id, filename))
      self.avatar = nil
   end

   def cancel_future_avatar_processing
      WorkAvatar.future_jobs_for_user(self.id).each(&:destroy)
      #ummm... tell them to reupload their avatar, I guess?
   end

   class WorkAvatar < Struct.new(:user_id, :path)
     def user
        @user ||= User.find(self.user_id)
     end
     def self.all_jobs
       Delayed::Job.scoped(:conditions => 'payload like "%WorkAvatar%"')
     end
     def self.future_jobs_for_user(user_id)
       all_jobs.scoped(:conditions => {:locked_at => nil}).select do |job|
          job.payload_object.user_id == user_id
       end
     end  
     def perform
        @user.avatar = File.open(path, 'rb')
        @user.save()
     end
   end          
end
```

It's possible someone has made a plugin make queryable objects like this. Perhaps searching on GitHub would be fruitful.

Note also that you'd have to work with any process monitoring tools you might have to cancel any running job worker processes that are being executed if you want to cancel a job that has `locked_at` and `locked_by` set.

Comment: There are 3 possibilities: 1) Using Thread without delayed_job; 2) Using rake jobs:work without using Thread in your code; 3) Spawning your own Delayed::Worker within a Thread in your application.

Comment: 1) and 3) are fairly similar, in that they run within the webserver's process (I presume you're running some kind of webservice, otherwise you'd probably not be using delayed_job.) - which could be bad depending on what your jobs are doing. (It's possible the Thread you're spawning could block on external IO and freeze the webserver.) Also, you'd still have to find some way to identify the job to your UI, unless you kept track of them in some global hash or something. It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the task into a `Timeout` statement.

```
require 'timeout'

class TaskWithTimeout < Struct.new(:parameter)
  def perform
    Timeout.timeout(10) do
      # ...
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    # the task took longer than 10 seconds
  end
end
```

Comment: i was asking if it's possible to terminate it manually. Like theres a button in the UI that when you click, the job cancels

Comment: You can't, unless you store the Record id somewhere and you delete it before it is executed.

Comment: would ruby threading solve my problem? see my updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do this. If you're concerned about a runaway job you should definitely wrap it in a timeout as Simone suggests. However, it sounds like you're in search of something more but I'm unclear on your end goal.

There will never be a way for a user to have a "cancel" button since this would involve finding a method to directly communicate with the worker running process running the job. It would be possible to add a signal handler to the worker so that you could do something like kill -USR1 pid to have it abort the job it's currently working and move on. Would this accomplish you goal?